# polynomials of two terms factoring

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am wondering if a multi-variable polynomial in $k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$ of two terms
$$f(x)=c_{1}\text{monomial}_{1}+c_{2}\text{monomial}_{2}$$
could be factored into a product of two polynomials of more than $2$ terms?

Of course, in $n=1$, there is an example of one of the factors has more than $2$ terms
$$x^{p}-1=(x-1)(x^{p-1}+\cdots+1).$$
But I don't think in $n=1$ one can get both factors having more than $2$ terms (even after a possible field extension). So I suspect in large $n$ case, it is also not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of such factorization for $\,n=2\,$ is the Sophie Germain identity:

$$
x_1^4 + 4 x_2^4 = \left(x_1^2+2x_1x_2+2x_2^2\right) \left(x_1^2-2x_1x_2+2x_2^2\right)
$$

For the general case, $\,x_1,x_2\,$ can be replaced with arbitrary monomials in the $\,n\,$ variables.

---

[ *EDIT* ] Other examples can be derived from [cyclotomic polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html) identities e.g.

$$
x^9 - 1 = \left(x-1\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right) \left(x^6+x^3+1\right)
$$

Comment: I see. I found that even for single variable case, there is a counterexample.